# Understanding and parsing warnings from gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, emacs, makefile

When compiling a .cpp file from Emacs through `M-x compile` (which runs the folder's Makefile), I see the following on the compilation buffer (displayed in compilation mode):

> ```
> In file included from: /path/to/file1:60,
>   from /path/to/file2.h:15,
>   from /path/to/file3.cpp:16:
> ```
>
> `/path/to/file4.h:28:2:` #warning  This file includes at least one deprecated  or antiquated header which may be removed without
>   further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface
>   with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement
>   headers and interfaces, consult the file `backward_warning.h`. To
>   disable this warning use `-Wno-deprecated`.

- Aside from the actual warning message, how should I understand this trace? i.e. which file generated the warning? (`file1`,`file2`, `file3` or `file4`)?
- Also, why is there a comma after the `file2` line, a colon after the `file3` line, the line with `file4` includes two numbers separated with two colons?

I am using Emacs `24.2.1`, with `gcc-4.4.5-x86_64`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construct that actually triggered the warning (a `#warning` preprocessor directive, in this case) is in `file4`.  The stuff above that is a trace of the `#include` stack, innermost-but-one first: in this case, `file3` included `file2`, which included `file1`, which included `file4`.

When gcc knows the column number of the construct that triggered a diagnostic, it prints the file name, a colon, the line number, another colon, and the column number, as you see on the `file4` line.  The first number is the line number (28) and the second number is the column number (in this case, you will find that the `#` of `#warning` is in column 2).  When gcc *doesn't* know the column number, it just prints the file name, a colon, and the line number.  This is the case for the `#include` stack, as it does not bother recording the exact column of `#include` directives.  Emacs' compilation-mode understands how to parse both these syntaxes: you will find that if you use <kbd>C-x  `</kbd> to page through the diagnostics, when there is a column number available, Emacs will place the cursor at the appropriate column.

The colons and commas at the ends of these reports are just to conform to English punctuation convention; they don't mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

1. The warning was generated in file4.h, on line 28.
2. The comma is because you're in the middle of a list, the colon designates the end of the list. The two numbers are line number and column number.

Comment: Thanks! Why is there a list? Was "gcc" 
smart enough to know that I included `file4.h` from three separate files? (`file1`, `file2`, `file3`)?

Comment: Also, why is there a **colon** (and not a **comma**) between the entry for `file3` and the one for `file4`?

Comment: @useer0000001: I fixed your formatting so that it might be a bit more obvious why there's a list. You get a full inclusion-list trace.

Answer (score 1):

Actually show its compilation path saying that:

```
in column 2 of line 28 of file4.h
that included from file1.h(line 60)
that included from file2.h(line 15)
that included from file3.cpp(line 16)
there was a warning ...
```

Every compiler should keep this track and it has nothing to do with GCC is smart or something!!
Since your compiler only compile `file3.cpp` and every other file will only parsed as a result of inclusion from this file.